# .htaccess content accessed via 2 urls always redirect to the first url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have a strange server set-up which I don't have a lot of control over. My production site looks like this:

```
/www/users/name    <- server points here
    /public    <- I want it to point here, but I don't have that option
        index.php    <- all requests should eventually end up here
```

This can be accessed via **www.test.com/users/name** AND **www.test.com/~name**

My dev site looks like this:

```
/www/name/public    <- dev server points here
    index.php    <- all requests should eventually end up here
```

This is only accessed via **www.test.dev**

I'm using a PHP Framework which forces my urls to always have the same base in order to work (Laravel). So **www.test.com/~name/stuff** will work, but **www.test.com/users/name/stuff** will NOT work. I would like my urls to always appear as the former to get around this issue.

I created a .htaccess file for my production base directory which will always forward to the public directory like this:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

The public directory has a .htaccess file like this which came with the framework I'm using (which I would like to not change since my dev site works just fine with it):

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

With just this, all **/~name** requests work perfectly, but none of the **/users/name** work. **How do I fix my production base directory .htaccess file to force all requests from /users/name to /~name?**

I have tried adding:

```
RedirectMatch ^/users/name/(.*)$ /~name/$1
```

Which does NOT work because the rewrites are revealed. For example, if I request **www.test.com/~name/stuff**, this shows up as **www.test.com/~name/public/index.php/stuff**. Without the RedirectMatch line, all ~name requests work perfectly fine.

Curiously, if I swap the rule above to:

```
RedirectMatch ^/~name/(.*)$ /users/name/$1
```

Everything works perfect except that my urls will always have **/users/name** instead of **/~name** like I would prefer.

Obviously, I am willing to live with this if what I ask is not possible. If someone could explain why the above works but the prior one does not that would be nice too. I did find that I could get the first one to work by adding **RedirectBase /~name** to BOTH .htaccess files, but as I mentioned above, I would like to not change the public .htaccess file since both my dev and production environments use it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /~name    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /users/name(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Still not sure why this works and what I described above doesn't... Speculation: I assume this has something to do with when the redirect happens from RedirectMatch. In this version, I am forcing the redirect from /users/name to /~name to always happen first, before any other rewrites happen. I believe that the redirect from RedirectMatch above was happening after the other Rewrites which was why the rewrites appeared in the address bar. I also think that the Redirect in the other direction worked fine because there is most likely an Alias for /~name to the actual path /users/name. So it has to replace /~name with /users/name in one case but not the other.